# React Native Elements ButtonGroup - Enable button when conditions are met

Tags: react-native, buttongroup, react-native-elements

I am using `react-native-elements` ButtonGroup with 3 buttons. I need to disable all buttons when the application starts, when conditions are met, I need to enable specific buttons.

Ive disabled all buttons using the false flag but I'm not sure how to enable specific buttons with a conditional statement and state.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
<ButtonGroup
  onPress={this.updateIndex}
  selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
  buttons={buttons}
  containerStyle={{ height: 100 }}
  //disabled={[0, 1, 2]}
  disabled={true}
/>

ADD_DETAILS(index) {
  if (index === 0) {
    console.log("clicked 0");
    this.requestDetails();
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the conditions you want?

Comment: There would be a few conditions, basically when the state changes in a function, a button should be enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your disabled buttons in your state
for example:

```
this.state = {
  selectedIndex: 2,
  disabled:[], // you store your disabled buttons here
}

<ButtonGroup
 onPress={this.updateIndex}
 selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
 buttons={buttons}
 containerStyle={{height: 100}}
 disabled={this.state.disabled}
/>
```

if you have ButtonGroup like this, you can disable buttons (for example first and third on button click ) like this:

```
  <Button
  title={"disable first and third buttons"}
  onPress={()=>{
    this.setState({disabled:[0,2]}); // here you update which buttons you want to disable
  }}/>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding

Answer (score 0):

As said by the docs, disable:

```
Controls if buttons are disabled. Setting true makes all of them disabled, while using an array only makes those indices disabled.
```

So creating a stucture like:

```
disabled={[1,2]}
```

would enable only the first button

To update it you should use a state variable and update it based off what you need, for example:

```
this.state={
   disabled=[0]
}
```

then the disabled prop would look like:

```
disabled={this.state.disabled}
```

And in your onPress function you should remove/add your buttons they way you need:

```
onPress={this.buttonGroupOnPress}
```

This will send to the function the index of the clicked button as a parameter:

```
buttonGroupOnPress = (index) =>{
   //your logic
   this.setState({ disabled: /* the new array of disabled buttons indexes */ })
}
```

Source: https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button_group.html#disabled

Comment: Thank you for responding